# Run a build script

Tags: .net, msbuild, build

So I have this build script I need to "run" or "install"? It's a .proj file. The directions are to run this script using MSBuild. How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt.

```
msbuild <filename>
```

`<filename>` is the path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Run using multiple concurrent processes (one per CPU), could be useful for "heavy" projects in case when you have multi-CPU computer:

```
msbuild /m /nr:false ProjectName.csproj
```